# first order dynamic process using a pandas aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I'd like to be able to create the following Data Frame in pandas

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 = f(c1) | c2 = a2 + b2 |
| a3 | b3 = f(c2) | c3 = a3 + b3 |

Ahead of time I know the A column, b1 and c1 are initial conditions, and f is a known function. The ith row of column is b_i = f(c_{i-1}) and c_i = a_i + b_i. All the a_i, b_i, c_i are floats.

I can do it using a for loop, but I'd love to be able to do this using pandas rolling/apply so I can scale it up and insert a groupby. I can't for the life of me figure it out though. Any clues?

Comment: a, b, c are numbers? In the third line: c3 = a2 + b2 or all the same: c3 = a3 + b3?

Comment: @inquirer yes a b c are numbers and yes c3 = a3 + b3! Thanks for that - have corrected the question.

Comment: answered. Without details, because I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, np.nan, np.nan], 'C': [1, np.nan, np.nan]})

print(df)

def my_func(x):
    df.loc[x.index, 'B'] = df.loc[x.index - 1, 'C'].values[0]
    df.loc[x.index, 'C'] = df.loc[x.index, 'A'].values[0] + df.loc[x.index, 'B'].values[0]


df[1:].groupby(df.index[1:]).apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

Input

```
   A    B    C
0  1  1.0  1.0
1  2  NaN  NaN
2  3  NaN  NaN
```

Output

```
   A    B    C
0  1  1.0  1.0
1  2  1.0  3.0
2  3  3.0  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! So I understand the function, it matches what I'm trying to achieve with my little bit of maths. I understand why you apply it to df[1:] so you take into account the initial conditions. But I don't quite understand the groupby! I can see that the computations doesn't work without it, but i don't understand why? The index is unique to every row!

Comment: Yes, the index is unique for each row. In terms of meaning, this is the same as a loop, all rows are sorted out.